# How to set delegate for subclass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, delegates

I'm writing own switch class. I'd like to add a delegate to it - examplary if we have UIImagePickerController we add UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to @interface of some viewcontroller and we can set methods like imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker...

I want to do something similar for my class - it's named HSwitch, so I want to add HSwitchDelegate to @interface of some view controller.

I would like to add to this delegate a method valueWasChanged, that I could set in viewController and which would be called each time when slider changes value.

How can I do that? I didn't do it yet, so... please help me :)
Thanks!

Comment: maybe `@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <HSwitchDelegate>`?

Comment: Are you asking: How to write a delegate? If yes, you may find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class is a switch, presumably it inherits from UIControl. If this is the case, don't introduce the complexity of delegates - use target-action instead, and send actions / register targets as you would with any other control. See the [UIControl class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details. `UIControlEventValueChanged` would be a suitable event for your needs.

Comment: Ohh, really, thanks! So my idea seems now really weird :P I just didn't think to look into UIControl reference. I managed it with [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];